# How do I pass a variable to a parent, but also return the output value? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, parent

I have two classes that are of the same type. One class A will be the parent to the other class B.

Class A and Class B have identical functions since they are the same type.

I want to call from Class B a function from Class A that need a value and will return a void pointer.

```
Class A
{
    void * funct(inputInt);
}

Class B
{
  protected:
  Class* parent   // here in header I set the parent class to it during construction

  ////
  void* callFunction(int value)
       {
         return this->parent.funct(value); 
       }
}
```

How do I get something like this to work?

Comment: you have a number of problems: first, `class` is the keyword used to define a class (all lowercase). second therefore, `parent` should be defined `A*` instead of `Class*`. thirdly, `A` is not a "parent" of `B`, a `B` *contains* an `A*`.

Comment: also your statement "class A and B ... are the same type" is not correct: as written they are completely different classes. if you were to use inheritance (like it sounds you want to) that may be more true. look into "c++ inheritance" for its syntax and mechanics to see if its what you want

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question the syntax for calling through a pointer is `->` and is a feature of the pointer `parent` not on the `return` statement. Your fixed line should look like this:

```
return parent->funct(value);
```